# password change for delegated users

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm having some problems running a powershell script when not on the domain controller.

The idea is that a delegated user such as a principal can change the passwords for students.

On the server I have added the membership into the powershell script allowing users to remote connect.

I have tested the code line by line on an end users account and computer.

However, when I run the script the import-module active directory doesn't work.

The error I get on the screen shows that it doesn't know what get-ADUser is followed by still being connected to the remote powershell connection on the domain controller.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DomainController
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Write - Host "********************************************************** `r`nDomainController - Studnet Password Configurator `r`n********************************************************** `r`n `r`nThis program will assist when a student requires a password change. `r`nPlease ensure that you verify the student prior to implementing the change. `r`n"
do
{ 
    $TargetUser = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a student user ID name'
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $TargetUser})
    {
        "Process user $TargetUser"
        Get-ADUser -Identity $TargetUser
        $passwordchange = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to change the user password? [y|n]'
        if ($passwordchange -eq 'y')
        {
            $newPassword = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please type new password' 
            Set-ADAccountPassword $TargetUser -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText '$newPassword')
            Write - Host "$TargetUser` password has now been changed to: $newPassword"
        } 
    }          
    else
    {
        Write - Host "$TargetUser` does not exist, please try again."
    }
        $answer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to see another user? [y|n]'

}
until ($answer -eq 'n') 
Exit-PSSession
```

Comment: Is the AD module actually installed on the remote server?  If so, is it installed in a location on the `PsModulePath`?  Running `Get-Module -ListAvailable` will show all the modules PowerShell can find on the path.

Comment: Yes, the AD module is installed on the remote server. There isn't any issue if I type it line by line, but when I try to run this within a script it won't compute. This the reason why I need to have this work from a script so that end users with privileges can run this when needing to change an end users password.

Comment: Using `Enter-PsSession` like this seems a bit awkward to me - it is meant to be interactive, not 'scripted'.  Does it make any difference if you gather all the info first, then execute the updates remotely in one block using `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: This is what they have asked for. So I don't have a choice but to make this work somehow.

Comment: What I mean is that `Enter-PsSession` is literally meant to be used at the command line, not inside a script.  You can still achieve the same objective of prompting the user, etc, from a script and calling the remote server with `Invoke-Command` to do the actual work.  Not saying this is the source of your specific issue, just that another technique may be better in general.

Comment: Oh, I understand Sorry. I tried this also today trying to do a invoke command from a spice work forum, but I got errors saying that it couldn't understand what invoke meant in red text. I wish I had a copy to show you but I saved over it